# Python - Find a specific mac address in a log file

Tags: python, regex, linux, mac-address, logfile

I want to extract specific Mac Address from a log file that can appear in different formats.

For example, on these three lines:

**Jun 16 10:24:28 (2248)  Login OK: cli 88-c9-d0-fd-13-65 via TLS tunnel)**

**Jun 16 10:24:35 (2258)  Login OK: cli f8:a9:d0:72:0a:dd via TLS tunnel)**

**Jun 16 10:24:44 (2273)  Login OK: cli 485a.3f12.a35a via TLS tunnel)**

with this regex:

```
([[:xdigit:]]{2}[:.-]?){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}
```

I can bring out all the mac address, within the linux command **less**.

Assuming to search **48:5a:3f:12:a3:5a**,how do I apply the same syntax with a specific mac address in Python?

I tried to write something like this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'([[:xdigit:]]{2}[:.-]?){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}')

for line in file:
   match = regex.search(line)
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to find a specific MAC address in a file?  If so, would `cat exampleFile | grep exampleMACAddress` work for you?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you're looking for `48[:.-]?5a[:.-]?3f[:.-]?12[:.-]?a3[:.-]?5a`? If the answer is yes, you should probably take a look at some regex tutorials.

Comment: I'm looking for **48:5a:3f:12:a3:5a** but it may appear in the format **485a.3f12.a35a** or **48-5a-3f-12-a3-5a**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\b[a-f0-9]{2}(?:([:-]?)[a-f0-9]{2}(?:\1[a-f0-9]{2}){4}|(?:\.?[a-f0-9]{2}){5})\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK3wZ7/1) (compile the regex object with the `re.I` flag).

**Explanation**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `[a-f0-9]{2}` - 2 xdigits
- `(?:` - start of  a non-capturing group with 2 alternative patterns:

  - `([:-]?)[a-f0-9]{2}(?:\1[a-f0-9]{2}){4}`:

    - `([:-]?)` - Group 1 capturing a delimiter that is either a `:` or `-`
    - `[a-f0-9]{2}` - 2 xdigits
    - `(?:\1[a-f0-9]{2}){4}` - 4 sequences of the delimiter in Group 1 and 2 xdigits
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:\.?[a-f0-9]{2}){5})` - 5 sequences of an optional (1 or 9) dot (`\.?`) and 2 xdigits.
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

[Sample Python demo](http://ideone.com/3ApN7l):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b[a-f0-9]{2}(?:([:-]?)[a-f0-9]{2}(?:\1[a-f0-9]{2}){4}|(?:\.?[a-f0-9]{2}){5})\b', re.IGNORECASE)
s = "Jun 16 10:24:28 (2248) Login OK: cli 88-c9-d0-fd-13-65 via TLS tunnel)\nJun 16 10:24:35 (2258) Login OK: cli f8:a9:d0:72:0a:dd via TLS tunnel)\nJun 16 10:24:44 (2273) Login OK: cli 485a.3f12.a35a via TLS tunnel)"
print([x.group() for x in p.finditer(s)])
# =>  ['88-c9-d0-fd-13-65', 'f8:a9:d0:72:0a:dd', '485a.3f12.a35a']
```